# instantiating unique elements of std::vector without a copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdvector

Say I have a `std::vector`, and I have a class. I want to initialize all of the elements of this vector, but for each of these elements, the constructor of the class will take unique arguments.

Do I need to give the class a copy constructor, or is there some weird syntax where I can instantiate elements of the `std::vector` without using an equal sign?

Comment: Some sample code, preferably a [mcve], would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create new elements in the vector directly using *emplacement* operations.

For example:

```
struct X { X(int, char); X(std::string, double, bool); };

std::vector<X> v;

v.emplace_back(1, 'x');              // direct-initializes element X(1, 'x')
v.emplace_back("foo", 1.5, false);   // ditto with element X("foo", 1.5, false)
```

Basically, `emplace_back` is like `push_back`, but directly creates the object (even using explicit constructors). Note that your `X` still needs to be copyable or movable, since pushing back new elements requires reallocation, which requires copying or moving. (Insertion in the middle moreover requires assignability.) Elements that are *unmovable* (e.g. `std::mutex`) can only go into node-based containers (e.g. `std::list`), also with emplacement. Once inserted, a node never moves.

Comment: Another option for unmovable objects is to use a vector of unique pointers